# Perl utf8 binmode unexpected results

Tags: xml, perl, utf-8

Why does binmode as raw produce the umlaut? Could any elaboration be given regarding how 'Zurich' String is stored internally in Perl? Just a little lost.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = "result-test-encoding-raw.xml";
open(my $fh,'>', $filename) or die "die";
#binmode $fh, ':utf8'; #bad umlaut
binmode $fh, ':raw'; #good umlaut

print $fh '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
print $fh '<node>';

my $line_text =  'Zürich';
print $fh $line_text;
print $fh '   next   ';
$line_text = 'Z&#252;rich';
print $fh $line_text;

print $fh '</node>';

close($fh);
```

Comment: Re "*how 'Zurich' String is stored internally in Perl*", The internal storage format is no consequence here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing `use utf8;`, which tells Perl your source code is encoded using UTF-8.

---

By default, source files are expected to be encoded using US-ASCII.

- If you encoded your source file using UTF-8, but you didn't tell this to Perl (by using `use utf8;`), Perl will treat it as encoded using US-ASCII. For string literals, Perl will simply map the bytes to string characters (rather than rejecting non-ASCII chars). This means that `$line_text` contains `5A.C3.BC.72.69.63.68`.

  When you pass these characters to a file handle with an encoding layer, the encoding layer will treat those characters as Unicode Code Points (`ZÃ¼rich`) and produce the appropriate bytes to represent those characters.
- If you encoded your source file using UTF-8, and if you told this to Perl (by using `use utf8;`), Perl will treat it as encoded using UTF-8 (decoding it accordingly). This means that `$line_text` contains `5A.FC.72.69.63.68`.

  When you pass these characters to a file handle with an encoding layer, the encoding layer will treat those characters as Unicode Code Points (`Zürich`) and produce the appropriate bytes to represent those characters.

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;                             # Source code is encoded using UTF-8.
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';  # Terminal expects UTF-8. Default encoding for files.

my $filename = "result-test-encoding-raw.xml";

open(my $fh, '>', $filename)
   or die("Can't create \"$filename\": $!\n");

...    
print $fh 'Zürich';
...
```

Note that I the use of `:encoding(UTF-8)` instead `:utf8`. The later is incorrect even though both appear equivalent in this example.

Comment: Isn't the default Perl source encoding Latin-1 rather than (7-bit) ASCII? At least `perldoc perlunifaq` claims so.

Comment: @amon, Not the way I see it. Try `perl -MEncode -e'print encode("iso-latin-1", "sub f\xEAte { }\n")' | perl`. In contrast, `perl -MEncode -e'print encode("UTF-8", "use utf8; sub f\xEAte { }\n")' | perl` works fine.

Comment: @amon, And when it comes to literals, it's neither ASCII nor latin-1 (`perl -e'print qq{printf "%vX\\n", "\x80";}' | perl` gives `80` even though `80` doesn't exist in either). It simply maps the bytes directly into characters. What happens is effectively closer to iso-latin-1 than US-ASCII, though.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Perl can be stored either as Byte Strings or Unicode Character strings.  In your case, you are defining Byte Strings.

Question:  In which encoding is your program source saved?

Your 1st assignment to `$line_text` is a byte string in your program source's encoding.  When you print this byte string to the file using `:raw`, it is dumped exactly as it was stored in your source.  If you print an encoded byte string using an encoder,like `:utf8` you get a doubly encoded string which is unlikely a good idea.  If your program is saved in UTF8, then you can `use utf8;` to decode that string literal into a Character string.  When you print a properly decoded Character string using `:utf8`, it will *encode* the characters correctly into UTF8.

**Moral of the story**:  While passing raw bytes can work in some situations, it's generally a better idea to decode your inputs (and string literals) and encode your outputs.